# Anystretch jQuery plugin and image cross-fading?

Tags: jquery-plugins, image-rotation

I'm using the Anystretch jQuery plugin to fill the area of a `<div>` with rotating images. At first an intro image fades in, and then the rotation starts. I'm using the images loaded in to an array, and then chosen at random:

```
$('body.home div.home-slider').anystretch(sliderImages[0], {speed: 250});
setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var chooseNewImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        $('body.home div.home-slider').anystretch(sliderImages[chooseNewImage]);
    }, 2500);
}, 3000);
```

What I'd like to happen with the rotation is for the images to cross-fade/transition. Is this possible? Can someone lend a hand as to how to achieve this?